# Issue with inner class scopes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, namespaces

so I've got a class structure with several levels of nesting of inner classes for namespacing purposes. It's no different from just having everything flat, but it's much cleaner and intuitive this way. Basically, we're using inner classes for better code organization.

I'm encountering some issues however:

I'll just post some example code rather than trying to explain them:

1)

```py
class Namespace1:
    class Class1:
        pass  # base methods go here

        class Subclass1(Namespace1.Class1):
            pass  # extended methods go here

        class Subclass2(Namespace1.Class1):
            pass  # extended methods go here

        class Subclass3(Namespace1.Class1):
            pass  # extended methods go here

    class Class2:
        pass  # base methods go here

        class Subclass1(Namespace1.Class2):
            pass  # extended methods go here

        # etc.
```

The issue with subclassing here is that `Namespace1.Class1` doesn't yet exist when you try to declare `Namespace1.Class1.Subclass1`, so it doesn't work. I'm assuming there's probably no way to fix this, but I'm mentioning this just in case there's some way to achieve this I'm not aware of.

So what I tried next was this:

```py
class Namespace1:
    class Class1:
        pass  # base methods go here

    class Class1Subclass1(Class1):
        pass  # extended methods go here

    class Class1Subclass2(Class1):
        pass  # extended methods go here

    class Class1Subclass3(Class1):
        pass  # extended methods go here

    class Class2:
        pass  # base methods go here

    class Class2Subclass1(Class2):
        pass  # extended methods go here

        # etc.
```

Which works, but I really dislike it for several reasons:

- We're now getting namespace collisions between the subclasses, so we can't call them (`Subclass1`, `Subclass2`, ...) anymore and now have to call them (`Class1Subclass1`, `Class1Subclass2`, ...)
- We've now lost the extra levels of indentation that acts to make the hierarchy visually explicit, this is awful once you're nested 4 levels deep and your class names start getting like 6 words long

So I thought of doing this:

2)

```py
class Namespace1:
    class Class1:
        pass  # base methods go here

    class Class1_:
        class Subclass1(Class1):
            pass  # extended methods go here

        class Subclass2(Class1):
            pass  # extended methods go here

        class Subclass3(Class1):
            pass  # extended methods go here

    class Class2:
        pass  # base methods go here

    class Class2_:
        class Subclass1(Class2):
            pass  # extended methods go here

        # etc.
```

It's not 100% ideal (the nicest way would be something like example 1 above), but this should in theory be possible to do. By the time the interpreter gets to creating `Namespace1.Class1_.Subclass1`, `Class1` should already exist. The issue I've got is that I don't know how to reference it, since I can't just reference it as `Namespace1.Class1` (since `Namespace1` doesn't yet exist), and I'm out of scope to reference it simply as `Class1`.

Does anyone have some idea of how I'd go about this?

And before anyone tells me to just use a module hierarchy to achieve this: I know it's an option, but I'd prefer to have it all in a single file in such a way that there's a single overview of it, since each of these classes is only about 3-5 lines long (only differing by a single method override). For this particular use-case it's good to see it all in one place, and the actual code I've got has like 3-4 levels of indentation with some classes having like 12+ subclasses. Navigating over 100 files (each of which is maybe 10 lines long) would be a nightmare.

Comment: Just a thought: does each class *need* is own global name? You can store references to an otherwise anonymous class in a container.

Comment: A module is already a namespace on it's own. And nesting class definitions is (usually) considered quite unpythonic (zen of python: "flat is better than nested"). NB: I'm NOT suggesting using one module per class (which is indeed a PITA, and at least as unpythonic as nested classes), just to NOT nest your subclasses this way.

Comment: Also, the fact that you have so many subclasses "only differing by a single method override" is a bit of a design smell to me. Impossible to tell without knowing much more about the real context and use case of course, but perhaps something like the strategy pattern might be a better fit ?

Answer (score 1):

Nested classes are stored as attributes of the outer class, so instead of specifying the base class of each nested class directly in its declaration, which you can't do for reasons you've already described, you can use a class decorator on the outer class to convert such attributes into subclasses of the outer class by re-creating them with a call to the `type` function with the outer class added to each inner class as a base class:

```
def nested_subclasses(cls):
    for name, obj in vars(cls).items():
        if isinstance(obj, type):
            setattr(cls, name, type(name, (cls,), dict(vars(obj))))
    return cls
```

so that:

```
class Namespace1:

    @nested_subclasses
    class Class1:
        def foo(self):
            print('bar')

        class Subclass1:
            pass

Namespace1.Class1.Subclass1().foo()
```

outputs:

```
bar
```

Comment: Heya, thanks for your answer! That's a cool approach. I'd never really used class decorators and tbh they seem pretty useful. The main issue I have with this solution is that code instrospection engines like Jedi, as well as linters and IDEs have limitations when it comes to decorators/metaclasses/dynamism and won't be able to understand this. So all uses of these classes will give you unresolved reference errors throughout your code. Do you by any chance have any other idea that doesn't involve metaprogramming?